# Reversing a string without using reverse function in COBOL

Tags: string, loops, reverse, move, cobol

my task is to reverse a string in cobol without using the reverse function.

So far i've got this:

```
MOVE 20 TO LOO.                       
MOVE 1  TO LOP.                       
MOVE 20 TO LOU.                       
MOVE EINA01 OF FORMAT1 TO WORTTXT1.   

PERFORM 20 TIMES                      
   MOVE WORTTXT1 (LOP:1) TO B (20:LOO)
   SUBTRACT 1 FROM LOO                
   ADD 1 TO LOP                       
   MOVE B  TO WORTTXT2 (20:LOU)       
   SUBTRACT 1 FROM LOU                
END-PERFORM.                          
MOVE WORTTXT2 TO AUSA01 OF FORMAT1.
```

AUSA01 is the output
EINA01 the input.

The problem i have right now is: If i write "Hello" into the input field, all i get is "00000000000h" he just reverses the first letter but its supposed to look like "             Hello".

Comment: Hello @Brian, By PERFORM 20 TIMES, I assume that you've got a 20 byte input field i.e. EINA01 is 20 bytes long. Reversing the string "hello" (5 bytes of character & 15 bytes of spaces) will result in the output having leading spaces. Do you also want to trim the leading spaces? Please clarify.

Comment: No, the program has to "reverse" the spaces aswell to make it look like it's completely mirrored e.g. "Hello . .  . . . .. .  . "   -> ". . .  . . . . .  olleH"                            ignore the dots, they're supposed to show the spaces i meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned that the program has to reverse the spaces as well, I suggest you to modify the PERFORM loop as shown below.

```
PERFORM 20 TIMES
MOVE WORTTXT1(LOP:1) TO B(LOO:1) 
SUBTRACT 1 FROM LOO
ADD 1 TO LOP
END-PERFORM.
```

Full program:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
01 EINA01 PIC X(20) VALUE 'Srinivasan          '.
01 WORTTXT1 PIC X(20) VALUE SPACES.
01 WORTTXT2 PIC X(20) VALUE SPACES.
01 AUSA01 PIC X(20) VALUE SPACES.
01 B PIC X(20) VALUE SPACES. 
01 LOO PIC 9(2) VALUE 0.
01 LOP PIC 9(2) VALUE 0.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.

MOVE 20 TO LOO.
MOVE 1 TO LOP.
MOVE EINA01 TO WORTTXT1.

PERFORM 20 TIMES
MOVE WORTTXT1(LOP:1) TO B(LOO:1) 
SUBTRACT 1 FROM LOO
ADD 1 TO LOP
END-PERFORM.

MOVE B TO AUSA01.
DISPLAY AUSA01.
STOP RUN.
```

Note: I'm not using the data items, B, LOU & WORTTXT2 as I felt that they are not required.

**Output:**

```
          nasavinirS
```

Try it [here](http://tpcg.io/9XxWfq)

Comment: Oh damn, it actually worked! Thank you, I made it way harder than it was supposed to... the problem i faced prior to the "Zeros" showing, was that he only reversed the last character of the input. But now everythings fixed, thanks alot!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to SO. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: you should consider using the length of function rather than just PERFORM 20 TIMES, then you can use PERFORM VARYING and use the length of the field as the exit condition

Comment: @SaggingRufus I agree. OP in his code snippet, had everything correct except for the position of a data item in Reference Modification. I just tried correcting OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use INSPECT to reverse a string. Code something like this to reverse an 8-character string SRC and get the result in TGT:

```
MOVE x'0807060504030201' TO TGT
INSPECT TGT CONVERTING x'0102030405060708' TO SRC
```

Note that you can use this trick to reorder a field in any desired way.